# SQL Pivot for 2 Value Columns

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to pivot sql dataset that looks like this.

```html
studentID year level Results Dimension
23096 7 576 reading
23096 7 640 writing
23096 7 704 spelling
23096 7 768 numeracy
23096 7 832 grammarPunctuation
23096 8 896 reading
23096 8 960 writing
23096 8 1024 spelling
23096 8 1088 numeracy
23096 8 1152 grammarPunctuation
23104 8 1216 reading
23104 8 1280 writing
23104 8 1344 spelling
23104 8 1408 numeracy
23104 8 1472 grammarPunctuation
23116 8 1536 reading
23116 8 1600 writing
23116 8 1664 spelling
23116 8 1728 grammarPunctuation
23117 7 1792 reading
23117 7 1856 writing
23117 7 1920 spelling
23117 7 1984 numeracy
23117 7 2048 grammarPunctuation
```

to looks like

```
StudentID Dimension   Year7_Results  Year8_Results  
 23096    reading             576                896     
 23096    writing             640                960 
 23096    spelling            704                1024
 23096    numeracy            768                1088
 23096    grammarPunctuation  832                1152
```

### My code

```
Select * from 
(
select StudentID,yearlevel,resultes,Dimantion  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by studentID,Dimension order by studentID,Dimension) AS PX,
'R' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by studentID,Dimension order by studentID,Dimension) as varchar(2) ) AS PX2
 from table
 )Temp
 PIVOT
 (
 MAX(Dimension) FOR PX IN ("1","2")
 )PVI1 
 PIVOT 
 (
 SUM(resultes) FOR PX2 IN ("R1","R2")
 )PIVOT2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use conditional aggregation instead of pivot:

**data sample:**

```html
declare @table as table (
       studentID  int          not null,
       yearlevel  int          not null,
       results    int          null,
       dimension  nvarchar(50) null
    )
    
    insert into @table
    values 
    (23096,7,576,'reading'),
    (23096,7,640,'writing'),
    (23096,7,704,'spelling'),
    (23096,7,768,'numeracy'),
    (23096,7,832,'grammarPunctuation'),
    (23096,8,896,'reading'),
    (23096,8,960,'writing'),
    (23096,8,1024,'spelling'),
    (23096,8,1088,'numeracy'),
    (23096,8,1152,'grammarPunctuation'),
    (23104,8,1216,'reading'),
    (23104,8,1280,'writing'),
    (23104,8,1344,'spelling'),
    (23104,8,1408,'numeracy'),
    (23104,8,1472,'grammarPunctuation'),
    (23116,8,1536,'reading'),
    (23116,8,1600,'writing'),
    (23116,8,1664,'spelling'),
    (23116,8,1728,'grammarPunctuation'),
    (23117,7,1792,'reading'),
    (23117,7,1856,'writing'),
    (23117,7,1920,'spelling'),
    (23117,7,1984,'numeracy'),
    (23117,7,2048,'grammarPunctuation')
```

**query:**

```
select  StudentID, 
        Dimension, 
        max(case when yearlevel = 7 then results end) as Year7_Results  ,
        max(case when yearlevel = 8 then results end) as Year8_Results  
from  @table
group by StudentID, Dimension
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, way cleaner

Answer (score 1):

You could solve it without using the pivot function. First create the table that holds all student records.

```sql
drop table if exists #student_results

create table #student_results (
   studentID  int          not null,
   year_level int          not null,
   Results    int          null,
   Dimension  nvarchar(50) null
)
```

Then insert some results from your example data.

```sql
insert into #student_results
values 
(23096, 7,  576, 'reading' )
, (23096,   7,  640, 'writing' )
, (23096,   7,  704, 'spelling' )
, (23096,   7,  768, 'numeracy' )
, (23096,   8,  960, 'writing')
, (23096,   8,  1024, 'spelling')
, (23096,   8,  1088, 'numeracy')
, (23096,   8,  1152, 'grammarPunctuation')
, (23104,   8,  1216, 'reading')
, (23104,   8,  1280, 'writing')
, (23104,   8,  1344, 'spelling')
, (23104,   8,  1408, 'numeracy')
, (23104,   8,  1472, 'grammarPunctuation')
, (23116,   8,  1536, 'reading')
, (23116,   8,  1600, 'writing')
, (23116,   8,  1664, 'spelling')
, (23116,   8,  1728, 'grammarPunctuation')
, (23117,   7,  1792, 'reading')
, (23117,   7,  1856, 'writing')
, (23117,   7,  1920, 'spelling')
, (23117,   7,  1984, 'numeracy')
, (23117,   7,  2048, 'grammarPunctuation')
;
```

With the use of CTE's we break up the logic.

1. We create a table with all combinations of studentID and Dimension.
2. Create a table with results from year 7
3. Create a table with results from year 8
4. Combine the results

```
with students
    as (select studentID
            , Dimension
        from   #student_results
        group by studentID
             , Dimension),
    year7
    as (select *
        from   #student_results
        where  year_level = 7),
    year8
    as (select *
        from   #student_results
        where  year_level = 8)
    select students.studentID
        , students.Dimension
        , year7.Results as Year7_Results
        , year8.Results as Year8_Results
    from   students
    left join year7
            on students.studentID = year7.studentID
              and students.Dimension = year7.Dimension
    left join year8
            on students.studentID = year8.studentID
              and students.Dimension = year8.Dimension;
```

[image: result]